# No sound output from external devices

Tags: sound, 20.04, headphones, external-monitor

I'm having issues getting sound output on my external sound devices. I currently have an external monitor with integrated speakers connected to a DisplayLink docking station and a Bluetooth headset. I believe this issue started after upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04, as I had no such issues with these sound devices before upgrading.

So far I've tried:

1. Setting both devices as default sound output in the sound settings. While I was able to select the correct device, the sound output comes from my laptop speakers. (An interesting side note is that I did manage to get sound output on my monitor by plugging and unplugging a 3mm jackplug on my laptop's headphone output while playing a video. However, when stopping and restarting video playback, the audio output reverts the integrated speaker.)
2. Change settings in `pavucontrol` and `alsamixer`. Neither did anything to get output from external sound units.
3. `lspci` detects soundcard (`Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)`). This seems to be working properly.
4. Reinstalling ALSA and PulseAudio (according to [maketecheasier's guide "How to Fix the No Sound Issue in Ubuntu"](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/)). This only made things worse. I am no longer able to test audio from any device in the sound settings (including integrated speakers), the aforementioned trick with the jackplug no longer works, and my Bluetooth headphones now disconnects immediately after connecting to the laptop.

Any ideas  how to get sound output from external devices and prevent my Bluetooth headset from disconnecting?

Comment: LOL!  I also faced this problem but mine was not worse as yours, I was getting the problem bcoz of default device which automatically gets changed after each reboot. I just deleted the inbuilt speaker option and after that, it recognizes the monitor-integrated speaker as default .

Comment: Same problem here after running a software update this morning (but still on `18.04`). The built-in speakers more or less work (they broke after following the guide, but I managed to fix them again), but not headphones. Running `pavucontrol` shows that it thinks the headphones are getting sound. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Hmm. After spending a day trying to fix this, it finally works, but I don't know why. The last thing I tried was to shut down the computer for a few minutes and restart it. I had restarted it many times during the day, but this was the first time I left it off for a while. No idea if that's actually the solution.

Comment: @Théophile I tried shutting down my computer as well, if only to exclude this as a possibility. This did not work, not for me at least. (I'd be surprised if it did.) I'm guessing there's another measure that actually got your headphones working again. Would you be able to you backtrack the steps you took before shutting down? I.e. is there some measure that was overlooked, or similar, that I haven't tried?

Comment: Too bad that didn't work for you; I truly wish I could say how to fix it. Perhaps `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`? Best of luck.